# I am getting following error when I create a django project in pycharm for Mac OS

Tags: python, django, macos, pip

I have been installed django using following command in terminal:

```
sudo pip3 install django
```

and I got this response:

```
kinredondeMacBook-Air:~ kinredon$ sudo pip3 install jiango
The directory '/Users/kinredon/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/kinredon/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: jiango in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: django<1.5,>=1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jiango)
```

then I create a django project in Pycharm and I get this following error:

```
Error:Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.core import management
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 54
except ImportError,e:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you use a supported version of django, this project `jiango` is using a very old version of django.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have solved this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that the folder is not owned by current user. So you need to change the owner by the following command:

```
sudo chown kinredon -R /Users/kinredon/Library/Caches/pip
```

Learn more about chown [here](http://www.linfo.org/chown.html).

Comment: I have executed this command:
`sudo chown kinredon:kinredon -R /Users/kinredon/Library/Caches/pip/http`
but it return this result:
`chown: -R: No such file or directory`
but I `ls /Users/kinredon/Library/Caches/pip/http`, this directory exists.

Comment: I have a try and get same results.

Comment: and I have successfully execute this command:
`pip3 install django`
and get a right result:
Requirement already satisfied: django in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
but when I create a django project I have get this error:Error:Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py", line 2, in from django.core import management File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 54 except ImportError,e: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Run `pip3 install Django`